# react-native - injecting javascript with WebView does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to inject javascript in react native Webiew

```
window.isRNWebView=true
```

so that on my web page I will be able to determine if the user is using the app or is using the browser on mobile

but I get undefined when trying to access window.isRNWebView in the client

this is my code

```
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <WebView
        style={{ marginTop: StatusBarHeight, flex: 1 }}
        source={{ uri: "http://192.168.1.11:3000" }}
        renderLoading={() => (
          <View
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#005790" />
          </View>
        )}
        startInLoadingState={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded="window.isRNWebView=true"
        injectedJavaScript="window.isRNWebView=true"
        allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures={true}
      />
    </View>
```